# Is it possible to get a user with just the password field?

Tags: users, login, user-roles, password

I tried doing something like this:

```
$user = $wpdb->get_row('
    SELECT * 
    FROM ' . $wpdb->users . ' 
    WHERE user_pass = "' . wp_hash_password('password') . '"'
);
```

But the `wp_hash_password` function generates a different string from the one in the database, is it possible?

What I'd like to do is have a custom form in my template that just asks for a password (think of it like the username/pwd screen to the WP admin area without the username) so I'd hash whatever the user inputs, compare it with my DB and if it matches take that user and log him in.

Comment: Ignoring the objection for doing it at all,  why do you think the password in the DB was generated with wp_hash_password? what value do you expect to be there and what value do you get?

Comment: [Very very bad man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VN29X2HCKpU)

Comment: @MarkKaplun I though that's they function WP used when creating a new user but it looks like they do something different. If I hash a string with `wp_hash_password` it generates a random string every time it runs

Comment: I agree with everyone else that says this is a terrible idea. That said, look at [wp_check_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password) documentation for how to match passwords.

Comment: I know it's not a very good idea but it's a request from a client and I just wanted to know if it was possible. I checked `wp_check_password` and I think it might work, I can loop through the users table and check every hash against the string the user inputs and if something matches then return that user's ID. I'll give it a go.

Comment: This indeed worked, thanks @Dan and all who helped I know it was an odd request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing in case someone else need a similar functionality:

```
// Simple text password
$client_password = $_POST['client_pwd'];

$users = get_users();

// Iterate over all users and see if the password matches
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // If it matches log the user in
    if (wp_check_password($client_password, $user->user_pass)) {
        $user = wp_signon(
            array(
                'user_login'    => $user->user_login,
                'user_password' => $client_password
            )
        );

        if (!is_wp_error($user)) {
            // Redirect or do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

### Password is not unique all the time.

According to `worst password` statistics, `password` is the most used Password of all time.

I'm pretty sure some of your users too use that password.

So multiple rows will contain the same hash.  Hence its not possible.

By the way, this is a weird question.

[image]

Comment: And even different passwords can result in identical hashes. Hashes are by their nature not collision safe.

Comment: That was just an example, I just want to know if it's possible to login a user by just asking the password, there should be a way to hash the text string to be the same as in the DB (kind of how the `wp_signon` function works). I guess hashes can be the same even if the password is different but really how likely is this scenario considering passwords have ~30 characters?

Comment: You enforce 30 character passwords? Are you confusing the hash with the password? The hash might have ~30 characters but the pass could still be "hi".

Comment: Giri, can you provide the link for the statistics?

Comment: @brasofilo Updated answer with statistics image

Comment: @javiervd, it is unlikely no matter how big is your password, but if it happens to you or on your site it is a total mess. Do you mind explaining the motivation for doing such a thing?

Comment: What I meant is that the password hash (the characters that are actually saved in the DB) are about 30 chars long so if I only have a handful of users it's not very likely that they will collision. What I'd like to do is have a custom form in my template that just asks for a password (think of it like the username/pwd screen to the WP admin area without the username) so I'd hash whatever the user inputs, compare it with my DB and if it matches take that user and log him in. I don't know why this talk about password security is taking place it has nothing to do with my question..

Comment: ok lets say you have only two users in your site. And lets say both use the password `123456`. now both users has the same password hash. When you query your database using password `123456`, it returns two users. Now how do you know which user trying to login ?

Comment: As Giri implies, the first step should be to ensure that every user has a different password. It is something that is probably possible to do, but you will need to write code to handle it in user creation time, giving the appropriate notice to the user.

Comment: This is not entirely correct! Password hashes are salted (salts randomly generated for each user) - see https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.1/wp-includes/class-phpass.php. In general the same password won't have the same hash in the database. But as @toscho has said, its not collision safe (albeit collisions very unlikely).

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments I'm going to answer a paraphrased question - "How to make a login form which shows only the password field in most cases".

The answer is to store the user name in a very long term cookie (a year?) every time the user logins.

```
function wpse82578_set_user_cookie($logged_in_cookie, $expire, $expiration, $user_id, $state) {
  if ($state == 'logged_in') { // user has logged in - store his name in a 'username' cookie
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    setcookie('username', $user->user_login, time() + 365*24*60*60, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
  }
}
add_action('set_logged_in_cookie', 10,5);
```

Now in you PHP code you can check if the cookie is set and show or hide the user name field in your form.

```
function wpse82578_echo_login_form() {
   ...
   if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])) { // already know the user name, no point in asking for it again so just put it as hidden field
     <input type="hidden" name="log" value="<?php esc_attr($_COOKIE['username'])?> />
   else { // show the field+label, ripped from wp_login_form
        <p class="login-username">
            <label for="' . esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $args['label_username'] ) . '</label>
            <input type="text" name="log" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id_username'] ) . '" class="input" value="' . esc_attr( $args['value_username'] ) . '" size="20" tabindex="10" />
        </p>
    }
}
```

No warranties for this code, but I think it is the best approximation to what you want without sacrificing security and messing with the WordPress user system.